# What is the most logical method to decide upon a value given a set of nested rules? and how do we store it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-structures, decision-tree

I'm needing to implement what to me looks like a decision tree (though searching on that term returns posts on finding out influencing factors in a decision process - which isn't what I'm after).

The system I'm building will be working out warranty periods to give a product installation based upon some criteria. The requirement is for the creation of a set of possible vectors (e.g. Installation Pitch, Profile, location, material type etc...) and for those vectors to be assembled by the user into a tree structure:

```
-- Profile == corrugate (warranty = 20 years)
  -- Pitch >= 0 && < 5 (warranty = 2 years)
  -- Pitch >= 5 && < 20 (warranty = 10 years)
-- Environment == coastal && distance <= 500 meters (warranty 2 years)
```

This is a simple case, but the theory is that I can then walk this tree when it comes time to figure out a warranty period, and then choose the lowest value that the tree produces given the supplied information.

Right now I can sensibly see this being stored as a tree in the database (it's a Rails app) and just writing some method to walk the tree and decide, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to approach this problem?

I'm going to have to repeat myself later in the project when I also implement another decision tree that will decide whether a warranty application needs further moderation by our warranty team. In that case the outcome from each node will just be true or false.

Seeing as it's a pretty crucial part of the app I'd like to get the structure right first time :) And perhaps learn something new along the way :)

Comment: Your question would read more clearly if you add 1 more Profile: I had to re-read to understand what kind of "tree" you meant since your example only has one branch!

Comment: Thans Andrew, I've updated that now :)

Comment: @BrendonMuir did you find a simple implementation or gem to accomplish your goal?

Comment: @westonplatter, I ended up using `ancestry` for the tree structure and `acts_as_list` for ordering. I used Single Table Inheritance to cater for different decision types. Works really well. I used `jstree` for actually displaying and allowing for drag and drop manipulation of the tree. In my logic we start at 0 years warranty, then step through the tree. The first rule that sets a warranty period, we take that period, and then seek to reduce it by only accepting lower values until we've walked the tree. All this is done with plain Ruby in a model from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a tree (or multiple trees--since you can only compare one vector element at a time before making a decision) translates this data very intuitively.  There may be a more compact way of doing it, but if anyone else will be looking at this code in the future, the tree method will help them to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks for that. You're right. I've begun implementing this project and have used the ancestry and acts_as_list gems to manage the backend of it and STI so that nodes in the tree can act differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for:
[Decision Trees in Ruby](http://www.igvita.com/2007/04/16/decision-tree-learning-in-ruby/)  - it even uses a similar example, based on some feed in data,  make a decision to opt-in or opt-out into a program. So based on your example - using  certain criteria decide if the warranty can be used or not. 
It uses a gem called 'decisiontree'

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Nick. I appreciate you having a stab at this one. Unfortunately that example and gem seem to be about optimising the decision logic rather than acting as a framework for decision making. I've come to the conclusion that since the tree structure needs to be able to be built by the actual end user in a web interface that I'll need to develop this manually. Efficiency isn't overly necessary as the tree will be relatively small and warranty applications will be infrequent.